# dataframe getting duplicated int all the columns instead of splitting the data into different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I am creating a dictionary by collecting data from ticks, then appending the dictionary into a new data frame with `3 columns` as same as in the dictionary. Issue is, the dictionary is getting appended into the data frame, but each column of the Dataframe is having a copy of the appended dictionaries as a single data frame. Sorry if i was not able to explain the issue clearly. I am very new to development and any support would be much appreciated. Is it bcoz of pycharm the way the result is displayed?

Also, can someone tell me how to time in seconds instead of numbers and how to do a re sampling on the appended data frame for 1 min on the LTP column.

from below is my code:

```
df_cols = ["Token", "LTP", "Volume"]

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=[], columns=df_cols, index=[])

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):  # retrive continius ticks in JSON format
    global data_frame, df_cols

data = dict()

for tick in ticks:
    token = tick["instrument_token"]
    ltp = tick["last_price"]
    volume = tick["volume"]
    timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())

    data[timestamp] = [token, ltp, volume]
    print(data)

tick_df = pd.DataFrame(data.values(), columns=df_cols, index=data.keys())

data_frame = data_frame.append(tick_df)

print(data_frame.tail())
```

Expected result

```
for -> print(data) = {'15:27:39.544348': [779521, 290.9, 11236092]}
```

for -> print(data_frame.tail()) =

```
    Token     LTP   Volume
15:27:39.544348   779521   290.9  11236092   
15:27:40.144447   779521   290.95 11236092
```

Actual result
for -> print(data) = `{'15:27:39.544348': [779521, 290.9, 11236092]}`

for -> print(data_frame.tail()) =

```
    Token                           LTP  \
15:27:39.544348   ([779521, 290.9, 11236092])   ([779521, 290.9, 11236092])   
15:27:40.144447  ([779521, 290.95, 11236092])  ([779521, 290.95, 11236092])   
                                       Volume  
15:27:39.544348   ([779521, 290.9, 11236092])  
15:27:40.144447  ([779521, 290.95, 11236092])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with data.values(), one solution that comes to me is to use **pd.dataframe.append** but in a way different than yours:

Before the loop you initialize tick_df:

```
tick_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols)
```

Then in the loop you update tick_df:

```
for tick in ticks:
    token = tick["instrument_token"]
    ltp = tick["last_price"]
    volume = tick["volume"]
    timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())

    tick_df = tick_df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df_cols,(token,ltp,volume))),index=[timestamp]))

print(tick_df.tail())
```

Comment: your solution worked bang on. Thanks a lot. I understood the whole solution, but can you tell me the usage of zip. Bcoz i didn't see this anywhere while i was learning.

Comment: @KG zip is used when you want to associate elements from one list (or iterable in general) to the elements of another and it returns an iterable(collection) of tuples. For example let's say we have 2 lists a=[1,2] and b=['x','y'] then zip(a,b) will give us something like ((1,'x'),(2,'y')) P.S: you can zip more than 2 iterables if you want, for example zip(a,b,c) is fine

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that data.values() contains all the data.You should try to append it either line by line or as numpy arrays. if you'll produce some small data we can help you out more.

Comment: Plz find some sample data below.Which i get form print(data)

{'15:28:05.948202': [779521, 290.95, 11246854]}
{'15:28:06.537399': [779521, 290.9, 11248058]}
{'15:28:07.148499': [779521, 290.95, 11251003]}
{'15:28:08.336873': [779521, 290.9, 11251003]}
{'15:28:09.552305': [779521, 290.95, 11251145]}
{'15:28:10.141859': [779521, 290.9, 11251382]}
{'15:28:11.357049': [779521, 290.95, 11251433]}
{'15:28:11.938267': [779521, 290.95, 11251467]}
{'15:28:12.562981': [779521, 290.95, 11251717]}
{'15:28:13.143340': [779521, 290.95, 11251717]}
{'15:28:14.348208': [779521, 290.95, 11251790]}